# Restrict direct file access htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need help to configure .htaccess file to restrict direct file access but would like the internal included files to work like images and pdf

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Help!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Internal include doesn't go through Apache config

Comment: What do you mean by internal include? Please provide an example